# Making sure only 30 participants enroll

Tags: php, queue, payment, checkout

I need to make a system in which only a certain amount of participants can enroll into a class.

The problem is that there is a moment that they leave the website to a payment providers portal and after the payment is done, they return to finalize the enrollment process.

So when person A adds the class to their cart and enters the payment portal, there still is 'room' in the class. It fills the class only when they return from the payment system. If person B starts the payment before person A is done, they too can enroll. Resulting in 31 entries.

It seems like this would require a sort of semaphore, but how would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Why not create a "line" or "queue" so that when Person A adds the class to their cart they are put in line. If they happen to be #30 then block Person B from adding the item to their cart with a message something like: "You are in line behind X person(s). If a slot in the class opens up you can proceed." Then if Person A cancels Person B can proceed.

Comment: It seems like there should be a cleaner way of handling this. I don't yet know how, but I'll find it :) Thanks!